# How to get all overlapping elements on 'mouseenter' in D3?

Tags: d3.js, event-handling

I have a multi-line chart in D3 with each line representing a "sample".

There is a large portion of the chart where the lines are overlapping, but some sections where they diverge. What I want to be able to do is when the mouse moves over the line, get the ID for each of the samples in that overlapping section.

Currently I can only get the ID for the top-most line. Is there a way to propagate the `'mouseenter'` event down all of the lines at that point and get the ID for each one?

Here is a minimal working example. In the section where the lines overlap I basically want `[line1, line2, line3]` or something similar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var myData = "x line1 line2 line3\n\
1 63.4 62.7 72.2\n\
2 58.0 59.9 67.7\n\
3 53.3 59.1 69.4\n\
4 55.7 55.7 55.7\n\
5 58.7 58.7 58.7\n\
6 77.0 77.0 77.0\n\
7 57.9 56.7 82.3\n\
8 61.8 56.8 78.9\n\
9 69.3 56.7 68.8\n\
10 71.2 60.1 68.7\n";
    var data = d3.tsvParse(myData);

    var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 50
    };
    var height = 500 - margin.bottom - margin.top,
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return X(d.x);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return Y(d.y);
      });

    var X = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
    var Y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
    var colour = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    colour.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "x";
    }));

    var lines = colour.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            x: +d.x,
            y: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    X.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.x;
    }));
    Y.domain([
      d3.min(lines, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.y;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(lines, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.y;
        });
      })
    ]);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(X));

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(Y));

    var gLines = svg.selectAll('.lines')
      .data(lines)
      .enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'lines');

    gLines.append('path')
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style('stroke', function(d) {
        return colour(d.name)
      })
      .style('fill', 'none')
      .on('mouseenter', function(d) {
        console.log(d.name);
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Document.elementsFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint). Although this method is still considered experimental it is [implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint#Browser_compatibility) by all major browsers.

The method will return **all** elements underneath the specified coordinates including all ancestors of the paths you are interested in, though. To get just your paths, you will have to apply an additional filtering:

```
d3.selectAll(document.elementsFromPoint(d3.event.x, d3.event.y)).filter("path");
```

Because Stack Snippets accessing the DOM tree somehow tend to freeze the browser, here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/es4404tm/) demonstrating the use.

Should this shortcoming get fixed in the future, here is the working demo:

```js
    var myData = "x line1 line2 line3\n\
1 63.4 62.7 72.2\n\
2 58.0 59.9 67.7\n\
3 53.3 59.1 69.4\n\
4 55.7 55.7 55.7\n\
5 58.7 58.7 58.7\n\
6 77.0 77.0 77.0\n\
7 57.9 56.7 82.3\n\
8 61.8 56.8 78.9\n\
9 69.3 56.7 68.8\n\
10 71.2 60.1 68.7\n";
    var data = d3.tsvParse(myData);

    var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 50
    };
    var height = 500 - margin.bottom - margin.top,
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return X(d.x);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return Y(d.y);
      });

    var X = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
    var Y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
    var colour = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    colour.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "x";
    }));

    var lines = colour.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            x: +d.x,
            y: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    X.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.x;
    }));
    Y.domain([
      d3.min(lines, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.y;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(lines, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.y;
        });
      })
    ]);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(X));

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(Y));

    var gLines = svg.selectAll('.lines')
      .data(lines)
      .enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'lines');

    gLines.append('path')
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style('stroke', function(d) {
        return colour(d.name)
      })
      .style('fill', 'none')
      .on('mouseenter', function(d) {
        console.dir(d3.selectAll(document.elementsFromPoint(d3.event.x, d3.event.y)).filter("path"));
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"Because Stack Snippets accessing the DOM tree somehow tend to freeze the browser"*... Not only that: try to console.log a D3 selection.

Comment: Great. Thanks for that @altocumulus. I'll go with this for now and hope it doesn't break in the future if the implementation of `elementsFromPoint()` changes.